# PHP and FTP transfers: files are sent one at a time?

Tags: php, sockets, ftp

i need to connect my PHP page to a FTP server and send 2 files: 'file1.txt' and 'file2.txt'.

No problem with the transfer, but i **MUST BE SURE** that the second file (file2.txt) will be sent only **AFTER** the first one.

What's the best practice to do this? Does PHP send files one at a time? Or maybe i need to open/close a connection for the first file and do the same for the second one?

Thanks

Comment: Everything in PHP happens in the order that you write it. It's not asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah i know it, but i don't know how does his "ftp connection" works in the specific so i prefer to ask to be absolutely sure. Thanks again